# How to create a Image slider UWP

Tags: uwp, slider

I'm starting a new app in UWP and I'm searching for a way to create a Image slider that can help me to view some of images in the app !

but I couldn't find a way to create that with any Nuget Plugin can anyone help me out here !

thanks for advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one using `FlipView`

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView1">
<Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" />
<Image Source="Assets/SplashScreen.png" />
<Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png" />
```

for more details you can check this link ! [FlipView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/flipview)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm looking for